# $f(X)$ is uncountable and hence $X$ is uncountable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

My question: let $f : X \to \Bbb R$ be a non-constant continuous function on a connected metric space and assume that $f(X)$ is uncountable; then $X$ is uncountable.

We know continuous image of a connected metric space is connected. Since connected space in $\Bbb R$ are intervals and the function is non-constant continuous function so $f(X)$ is an interval in $\Bbb R$ and hence uncountable.

Is the proof correct?? How does it follows that $X$ is uncountable?

Comment: Are you talking about connected or countable? The question mixes both terms...

Comment: I changed "non constant" to "non-constant". In recent years I have so often encountered this usage, in which people write "non whatever" instead of either "non-whatever" or "nonwhatever", as if "non" were a word rather than a prefix, that I may some day start to suspect that this is not merely a typo and maybe some people think that is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Nothing about topology seems to be required here...maybe preimages were desired?

Comment: You can find numerous questions and answers on this site which show that if $f\colon A\to B$ and $A$ is countable, then $f(A)$ is countable. So if $f(A)$ is uncountable, $A$ has to be countable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I assume you meant "$A$ has to be **un**countable".

Comment: @Alex: Of course. Don't read what I write, read what I mean. :-)

Answer (score 4):

We know that $f(X)$ is uncountable. By definition, for each $y \in f(X)$ there is an $x \in X$ for which $f(x) = y$.

So for each $y \in f(X)$, we can assign $g(y) = x$ for some $X$ for which $f(x) = y$.

To show that $g$ is an injection, consider $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$. Thus we have $y_1 = f(g(y_1)) = f(g(y_2)) = y_2$. This tells us that if $y_1\neq y_2$, $g(y_1) \neq g(y_2)$. Therefore we have established that $g$ is an injection from $f(X)$ to $X$.

This means that $X$ is at least as large as $f(X)$ in the sense of cardinality. Hence, $X$ is uncountable.

Your reasoning as to why $f(X)$ is uncountable is correct.